# How to remove characters after and including the last period in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to use regex to replace everything after and including the dot.

This is my string:

```
file.exe.abc.dux
```

I need to use regex such that my final result is:

```
file.exe.abc
```

I am currently running the codes in 2 different lines:
`[^\\.]+$` followed by `\.$` to achieve the result above.

I would want to know if there is a single regex pattern to achieve the above result.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\.[^.]+$', '', s)`?

Comment: `os.path.splitext` works too

Answer (score 1):

Using [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'^.*(?=\.)', s))        # ['file.exe.abc']
print(re.search(r'^.*(?=\.)', s)[0])      # file.exe.abc
```

Using [`rsplit()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html):

```
s = 'file.exe.abc.dux'

print(s.rsplit('.', 1)[0])                 # file.exe.abc
```

Using [`rindex()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rindex.htm):

```
print(s[:s.rindex(".")])                   # file.exe.abc
```